# How to get groups from time-series data that update every month in Python/pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, pandas-groupby, portfolio

I have time-series data of stock returns that look like this:
`Stock   Date    Return
 A     2012-01     6
 A     2012-02     4
 A       ...      ...
 A     2019-08     2
 B     2012-01     5
 B       ...      ...
 B     2019-08     5
...      ...      ...`

I want to create stock portfolios for the complete time frame based on return performance that update every month:
Portfolio 1 - best   10% of each month
Portfolio 2 - next   20% of each month
Portfolio 3 - next   40% of each month
Portfolio 4 - next   20% of each month
Portfolio 5 - lowest 10% of each month

Every month, I would like to assign each stock to one of the five portfolios based on its performance ranking. For example, if the return of stock A is in the best 10% in 2012-01, I want to assign it to portfolio 1. If it then drops in performance and only scores within the best the 30% - 20% in 2012-02, I want to move it to portfolio 2.

For each of the five portfolios, I want to get a DataFrame that should ideally look like this:
`Portfolio   Date   Stocks included  Stock Return
      1     2012-01       A               6
      1     2012-01      ...             ...
      1     2012-01      ...             ...
      1     2012-02      ...             ...
     ...     ...         ...             ...
      1     2019-08      ...             ...`

What is the best way to do this in pandas? Any hints would be greatly appreciated!
I am new to pandas and thus not very experienced yet. I tried `groupby` and `pd.cut` but have not been able to get it right.

Here is what I have written so far. It seems to work but I am not sure if it is the best way to do it.

```
# Group by Date
grouped = df_total.groupby('Date')

# Iterate through every month; get portfolio ranks and store them in df_total
for name, group in grouped:
    portfolio_category = pd.qcut(group.Return, q=[0, .1, .3, .7, .9, 1], labels=False)
    df_total['PortfolioNr'].update(portfolio_category)

# Portfolio 1 (top 10%)
df_portfolio10 = df_total.loc[df_total['PortfolioNr'] == 4.0]
df_portfolio10 = df_portfolio10.sort_values(by=['Date'])

# Portfolio 2 (next 20%)
df_portfolio10to30 = df_total.loc[df_total['PortfolioNr'] == 3.0]
df_portfolio10to30 = df_portfolio10to30.sort_values(by=['Date'])

# Portfolio 3 (next 40%)
df_portfolio30to70 = df_total.loc[df_total['PortfolioNr'] == 2.0]
df_portfolio30to70 = df_portfolio30to70.sort_values(by=['Date'])

# Portfolio 4 (next 20%)
df_portfolio70to90 = df_total.loc[df_total['PortfolioNr'] == 1.0]
df_portfolio70to90 = df_portfolio70to90.sort_values(by=['Date'])

# Portfolio 5 (lowest 10%)
df_portfolio90to100 = df_total.loc[df_total['PortfolioNr'] == 0.0]
df_portfolio90to100 = df_portfolio90to100.sort_values(by=['Date'])
```

Comment: Can you share the code you've written?

Comment: Sure. I added it to the question.